# Printing 1D array through loop not working as expected

Tags: c, arrays, loops

Currently, the first function `info()`, works fine and returns the whole array. This seems pass to the `kurtosis()` function fine also, as I have tested to see if each element prints in the function manually. However when attempting to print off each element through a loop, it only seems to print the value in the first iteration; for the iterations after this it prints `0`. Weirdly this still happens when replacing `i` with a constant number.

```
#include <stdio.h>

double * info(){//function for obtaining up to 10 numbers
    int i;
    int x=0;
    double numbers[10];
    for (i = 1; i < 11; i++){
        printf("\nPlease enter value %d:", i);
        scanf("%lf", &numbers[i]);
        x++;//counting number of entries
        if(numbers[i] <0){//stops accepting numbers if user enters negative number
            x--;
            numbers[i] = -1;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("%d numbers entered.\n", x);
    return numbers;
}
double kurtosis(double * numbers){
    int i, x;   
    double mean, numerator, denominator, sum;

    for (i = 1; i < 11; i = i + 1){ //irrelevant loop; will be used later on
        if (numbers[i] == -1){
        x = i-1;
        break;
        }
    }

    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++){
        printf("%lf\n", numbers[i]);//printing each value in the array
    }   
}

int main(void){
    double * numbers = info();
    double kurtno;
    kurtno = kurtosis(numbers);//passing the array to the kurtosis function
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems in your code.

---

```
double numbers[10];
```

this is a local array to the function `info()`. Accessing it once the function has returned invokes Undefined Behavior.

---

The function `kurtosis()` has `return` type as `double`, but nothing is getting returned from `kurtosis()`.

---

If you are trying to access the `number[]` array from `info()` in the function `kurtosis()`, then also there is an error.

The array index always start from `0`. So `number[10]` will have indices starting from `0` to `9`.

The loop `for (i = 1; i < 11; i = i + 1)` would access `number[10]` which is out of bound.

Change it to

```
for (i = 1; i < 10; i = i + 1)
```

---

**To Make it Work**

Use `malloc()`. Memory allocated using `malloc()` stays in scope in between function calls.

```
double* numbers = malloc(10*sizeof(double));
```

Comment: and the loop conditions, too.

Comment: Thanks, is there another way you could recommend for returning the array form info(), as this was the only way I found.

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue in your code is, in your function `info()`, `numbers` is local to that function. `numbers` run out of its lifetime when you return from the function call, so, in the caller, the returned address is not valid anymore. By returning the address of that function, and using it later, you're invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Also, as mentioned by others, the second function lacks a return value.

Then, the loop

```
 for (i = 1; i < 11; i++)
```

is also wrong, as C arrays have 0-based indexing. The loop should run

```
 for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

Comment: This was the only way I found for returning the function to the main, is there another you could suggest? Also in terms of 0-based indexing, this is what I thought, but it then seemed to work with 1-based.

Comment: @Ollie yes, make `numbers` a pointer, allocate memory dynamically using `malloc()` and then you can return `numbers` from `info()`.

Comment: @Ollie also, _seem_ to work is one of the many _beauties_ of [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: @Ollie 1-based is not problem , problem is that it will access index `11` due to our condition , which will cause UB .

Comment: @Ollie an alternative to allocating memory with `malloc()` is to declare the `numbers[]` array as `static`. However, this makes the function non-reentrant - every call will overwrite and return a pointer to the same block of memory. If you do use `malloc()` (or better, `calloc()`), and return a pointer to the dynamic memory, the caller needs to `free()` the memory when it has finished with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your first function returns a local variable whose scope is inside function blocks.

Your second function does not return anything despite of having type `double`.

Both of them invokes *undefined behaviour*.

To add more your loop conditions access index out of bounds another reason for UB . Loop condition should be `i=0` till `i<10` (as also pointed by others).

What you can do is -

**1.** In function `info` ,declare as `double *` and allocate memory to it .

**2.** Pass array to function `info` from calling function itself.